# Python Regular Expression Matching: ## ##

Tags: python, regex

Im new to python and regular expressions. Im searching a file line by line for the occurrence of ##random_string##, and i want to be able to capture the random_string in-between the ##s.

Ive tried both patterns but no luck =/

```
pattern1=r'[##]()[##]'
pattern2=r'\#{2}()\#{2}'

prog=re.compile(pattern1)
result=prog1.search(line)
if result:
  print result.group(0)
```

Thanks for any help =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
'##(.*?)##'
```

The problem with your regex is that you are trying to match an empty string between the `##` using a `()`, you should be using `.*?` to match anything or a `.+?` to match any non-empty thing.

Your first regex `[##]()[##]` has an additional bug. A character class matches a single character, example: `[ab]` matches an `a` or `b` but not both.
 So `[##]` does not match `##`, in fact it's redundant to have duplicate characters in a character class, so `[##]` is same as `[#]` which is same as `#`.

Your second regex `'\#{2}()\#{2}'` is almost correct but for the empty match thing. Also note that a `#` is not a meta character ( like `.`, `+`, `*`) hence you need *not* escape it. So you can drop the `\` in `\#`, but having it is *not* an error.

Comment: `##(.*?)##` equals `##(.*)##`

Comment: @ guilin: No, it does not. `.*?` is a non-greedy match, whereas `.*` is a greedy match.

Comment: For instance, if the string were `'##a## ##b##'`, the former would match twice (once for `a`, the other for `b`), whereas the latter would match only once (and consider the inner part to be `a## ##b`).

Answer (score 0):

Your group is empty.

```
'##(.+?)##'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
'##([^#]*)##'
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

If your line has multiple `##()##` , what would be your output? ie, if there is overlapping of the patterns and you want to get those overlaps

```
>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah blah ##  i want 2 ## blah"
>>> line.split("##")[1:-1]
[' i want 1 ', ' blah blah ', '  i want 2 ']

>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah"
>>> line.split("##")[1:-1]
[' i want 1 ']

>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah ## "
>>> line.split("##")[1:-1]
[' i want 1 ', ' blah ']
>>>
```

If you don't want overlapping,

```
>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah ## i want ## "
>>> [i for n,i in enumerate(line.split("##")[1:]) if n%2==0]
[' i want 1 ', ' i want ']

>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah "
>>> [i for n,i in enumerate(line.split("##")[1:]) if n%2==0]
[' i want 1 ']

>>> line="blah ## i want 1 ## blah ## iwant2 ## junk ## i want 3 ## ..."
>>> [i for n,i in enumerate(line.split("##")[1:]) if n%2==0]
[' i want 1 ', ' iwant2 ', ' i want 3 ']
>>>
```